# What is the Time Complexity of Below Code

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I need to calculate the time complexity of the following code:

```
for (let i = 1; i < n; i = i * 2) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

and please explain how to calculate complexities in log

Comment: What else would you expect? Do you know *how* to determine the complexity?

Comment: Try to evaluate `log n` expression. and comapare it with your program

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the mathematical complexity (which can be found on wikipedia), and talking completely in layman terms, you reach O(log n) whenever you reduce the amount of work by some percentage each iteration.

In your loop example, running it in reverse (from n to zero), you reduce the amount of remaining work in half (50%) each step.

However, `i = i * 1.4` would be O(log n) as well.